# BeautifulSoup .get_text() element returns no results

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

For some reason the code below does not return any results on different laptop's running the same python version 3.8.1 64bit and I cannot figure out why... I've tried 3 different laptops and chart is printing results only on one of them.

Does anyone have any ideas what might have been different or what's the reason the exact same code works on one machine, but not another?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def check_facebook():

URL = 'https://downdetector.com/status/facebook/'

browser = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=browser)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


chart = soup.find("div",{"class":"popover-container justify-content-center p-relative"}).script.get_text()


print("Facebook chart:", chart)

check_facebook()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.get_text()` use `.string` property to get the contents of `<script>` tag:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def check_facebook():
    URL = 'https://downdetector.com/status/facebook/'
    browser = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=browser)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    chart = soup.find("div",{"class":"popover-container justify-content-center p-relative"}).script.string
    print('Status:', re.search(r"status: '(.*?)'", chart).group(1))
    print('Baseline:', re.search(r"baseline: (\d+)", chart).group(1))
    print('Company:', re.search(r"company: '(.*?)'", chart).group(1))
    print('Max:', re.search(r"max: (\d+)", chart).group(1))
    for x, y in re.findall(r"x: '(.*?)', y: (\d+)", chart):
        print(x, y)

check_facebook()
```

Prints:

```
Status: success
Baseline: 28
Company: Facebook
Max: 37
2020-07-24T18:29:28.479584-04:00 33
2020-07-24T18:44:28.479584-04:00 27
2020-07-24T18:59:28.479584-04:00 31

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, sadly but this solution does not work for me as I need to see other from chart such as 'status ', 'baseline ', 'max: '.

I'm trying to make get_text() to work on other machines, but for some reason it doesn't return anything. When the .get_text() works, I use the below to gather e.g 'max: ' number:

chart = soup.find("div",{"class":"popover-container justify-content-center p-relative"}).script.get_text()

    max_val = chart.split("max: ")[1].split(",")[0]

    print("Facebook max reports over the last 24 hours:", max_val)

Comment: @Shaggy I updated my answer. Just do `print(chart)` to print all content of `<script>` tag.